# Firewall create rule that allow only one program connect to specific ip

Tags: windows, firewall

I am went to add rule to my firewall that will allow only to my program to connect to the ip address of my product. but I went the other ip address to be open for all program,and if this is not possible in window firewall so which fire wall is allow that . I need it to be set from terminal like netsh
I already tried to block the all access and then add one allow program but it didn't worked